# Differential of the squared Euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(t)=\|g(.,t)\|_2$ with $g$ a differentiable function, I want to calculate the differential of $(f(t))^2$:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(f(t))^2=2 f(t) \frac{d}{dt}f(t)=2 \|g(.,t)\|_2 \frac{d}{dt}\|g(.,t)\|_2$$
is it correct ?

Comment: The Euclidean norm of a scalar function? The square of this would be the same function squared.

Answer (score 1):

Use that ${\lVert\cdot\rVert}_2$ is an inner product norm. We get

$${f(t)}^2 = \langle g(\cdot,t),g(\cdot, t)\rangle$$

and hence $\frac{d}{dt}\left({f(t)}^2\right) = 2\left\langle \frac{d}{dt}g(\cdot,t), g(\cdot,t)\right\rangle$.

Comment: it's $(f(t))^2$..

Comment: Fixed. ${}{}{}$